# Always get the last two params of the dynamic URL with useParams. How to define <Route path="*/:parentName/:level">

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

[Here is the codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/45lqrq?file=%2Fsrc%2FGitHubTree.jsx%3A18%2C29&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clttypxin00063b6gxhkoygaz%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clttypxin00023b6gs4b0gfxm%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clttypxin00043b6gi38b8pe1%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clttypxin00053b6g2q3s5og6%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B51.974461401891496%252C48.025538598108504%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clttypxin00023b6gs4b0gfxm%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clttypxin00023b6gs4b0gfxm%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clttzg3wb00023b6gp5p5ldum%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A18%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A29%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A18%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A29%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FGitHubTree.jsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clttzg3wb00023b6gp5p5ldum%2522%257D%252C%2522clttypxin00053b6g2q3s5og6%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clttypxin00053b6g2q3s5og6%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clttyq8ay00a83b6geunleqdi%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522Development%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clttyq8ay00a83b6geunleqdi%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252Ftree%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clttypxin00043b6gi38b8pe1%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clttypxin00043b6gi38b8pe1%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clttyq43u008m3b6g3krjp8bh%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clttypxin00033b6g8y9jny60%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clttypy30001bdbf804m23uj1%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522Development%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clttyq43u008m3b6g3krjp8bh%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D). My question is around extracting the last two params of the dynamic route.

I need to create UI like Github. I am expecting the Githubtree to create it's new instance on click of any element of the tree. I am able to get it through for two levels but the third level is not rendering. I know the problem with my code. My Routes have
<Route path=":parentName/:level/*" element={} />

whereas in my code I am expecting it to pick latest parentName and level.
If my URL is https://45lqrq-5173.csb.app/tree/Parent1/2/tree/Child11/3 , I want parentName to be Child11 and level to be 3, whereas because of the way route is defined parent always stays as Parent1 and level as 2

I tried <Route path="*/:parentName/:level" element={} /> but that doesn't work either. Is there any way I can pick the last two elements of the URL.

App.js

```
import { gitTreeData } from "./gitTreeData";
import GitHubTree from "./GitHubTree";
import { Route, Routes, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="tree">
        <Route path=":parentName/:level/*" element={<GitHubTree />} />
        <Route index={true} element={<GitHubTree />} />
      </Route>
      <Route index={true} element={<Navigate to="/tree" />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

GitHubTree.js

```
import React from "react";
import { gitTreeData } from "./gitTreeData";
import { Route, Routes, Link, useParams, useMatch } from "react-router-dom";

const GitHubTree = () => {
  let { level, parentName } = useParams();

  const renderTreeRoot = () => {
    return gitTreeData.map((child) => {
      //For root elements
      if (!level && !child.parent) {
        return (
          <Link key={child.id} to={`${child.name}/${Number(child.level) + 1}`}>
            <li key={child.id}>{child.name}</li>
          </Link>
        );
      } else {
        //For child elements
        if (child.parent === parentName) {
          return (
            <Link
              key={child.id}
              to={`tree/${child.name}/${Number(child.level) + 1}`}
            >
              <li key={child.id}>{child.name}</li>
            </Link>
          );
        }
      }
      return null;
    });
  };
  return renderTreeRoot();
};

export default GitHubTree;
```

Comment: I was able to get around the problem by passing state in Link and then accessing it using useLocation

            <Link key={child.id} state={{ parentName:child.name, childLevel:Number(child.level)+1 }} to={`${child.name}`}>
                        <li key={child.id}>{child.name}</li>
            </Link>

Accessing:  const { parentName, childLevel } = state || {};

But my original question stays, is there a better way to tell that pick up the latest ids from route